# How does nextLine work with scanner?

Tags: java, split

I am trying to split "sisestus" into different words by using space as a separator, but by just using sc.next() doesn't allow me to enter a string with spaces so i read that i should use .nextLine(), but it doesn't work at all. How do i solve it?

```
public class Sisestamine {
int read;
int veerud;
double Maatriks[][];
java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

Sisestamine() {
    System.out.println("Enter matrix dimensions (format NxM)");

    String[] abi = sc.next().split("x");
    this.read = Integer.parseInt(abi[0]);
    this.veerud = Integer.parseInt(abi[1]);
    this.Maatriks = new double[read][veerud];

    System.out.println("Enter the matrix: (x x x x etc..)");
    for (int i = 0; i < read; i++) {
        String sisestus = sc.next();
                  //String sisestus = sc.nextLine(); 
        abi = sisestus.split(" "); 
        System.out.print(abi);
        for (int j = 0; j < abi.length; j++) {
            this.Maatriks[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(abi[j]);
        }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by, "doesn't work at all"? Can you tell us the pertinent details about your problem? Usually the more we know, the better we understand your problem, the better the help we can provide.

Comment: It gives me an "empty string" error after entering the matrix dimensions (i can't even start to enter the real matrix).

Comment: I don't see where you're calling `nextLine()` in the code above. Please post the code causing your error, perhaps as an edit on the bottom of your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem could be because you're using `sc.next()` at one part of your program and then `sc.nextLine()` later, and the second call swallows the end of line (EOL) token that was left hanging from the prior call to `next()`. A solution is to use `sc.nextLine()` for all invocations. In other words, change *all* `sc.next()` to `sc.nextLine()`.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i meant. Great ;) Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Faz3r: you're welcome. I sometimes use multiple Scanner objects, one to get lines, and than others to work with tokens in the individual lines -- in other words initialize the line Scanner with the line String. If you go this route, be sure to close any Scanner when you're done using it.